# SWT: cleaning up before application exit

Tags: java, swt

What is the best way for an SWT application to clean up resources before application exit? I see two options:

1) Add a DisposeListener to main window (or better, to the `Display`). Will it get run if an uncaught exception happens?

2) Use a [shutdown hook](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). Any problems to be aware of there which aren't mentioned in [Design of the Shutdown Hooks API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an uncaught exception happen, you may end up with [`java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!`](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg33638.html) exception:

> This is usually caused by one of the other exceptions, especially on close, and often times the "disposed to early" errors are listed before the exception that caused them. i.e.
>
> 1. workbench is closing
> 2. one part thows an error that can't be caught.
> 3. all the following parts aren't closed, and so generate this error
> 4. the error that cause the problem percolates up to the top of the
>      stack and is printed out.

In your case, I am not sure how it would affect your Listener, so a shutdown hook might be a fail-safe, provided it still can access resources to dispose (which may not be always the case).

Comment: Nice to know. In this case I'll probably go with a shutdown hook, since I can access the resources I'm worried about.